# Upload file to FTP server with Swift

Tags: swift, ftp, nsurl

I'm using a framework `RebekkaTouch` to upload files from my Swift app to an FTP server, just like:

```
if let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myFile", withExtension: "txt") {
    let path = "myFile.txt"
    session.upload(URL, path: path) {
        (result, error) -> Void in
        print("result:\n\(result), error: \(error)\n\n")
    }
}
```

This works great for files I manually upload via Xcode. But I don't seem to be able to find the file path for file I download and store locally on the `Documents` directory dynamically.

Say, I know I have this file: `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3D92EA55-01E0/Documents/SomeFile.txt`

I know it's there because I get the path after looping through `NSFileManager.defaultManager()` but I can't convert it no `NSURL` so I can upload it.

Any ideas?

////UPDATE

This is where is dies:

```
let file = "myFile.txt"
if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
    //path will be stored here
    let sPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
    print(sPath) //  printing the file path

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: sPath)!

    let destinationFile = "myFile.txt"
    FTPSession.upload(url, path: destinationFile) { // <-- Dies here
        (result, error) -> Void in
        print("- Result:\n\(result), error: \(error)\n\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example

> This code is fully tested on Swift 2.0

```
 let file = "SomeFile.txt"
        if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
           //path will be stored here
            let sPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

      print(sPath) //  printing the file path
        }
```

than you can perform the upload

> EDIT AS ASKED IN COMMENT ABOUT CONVERTING STRING TO NSURL

```
let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: stringofURL)! //replace stringofURL to sPath
```

> UPDATED YOUR CODE

```
let file = "myFile.txt"
if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
    //path will be stored here
    let sPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
    print(sPath) //  printing the file path

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: sPath)!

    let destinationFile = "myFile.txt"
    session.upload(url, path: destinationFile) { // here was the error it should be session not FTPsession
        (result, error) -> Void in
        print("- Result:\n\(result), error: \(error)\n\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I convert `sPath` to `NSURL`? I've tried `let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: sPath)` but I get the usual error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED THE POST

Comment: If you found the post useful don't forget to upvote and accept  :)

Comment: Thanks! although I've tried all NSURL(...) options and always crashes while unwrapping an optional value... should the path start with `/var/mobile/Containers/` or `file:///var/mobile/Containers/`

Comment: file:///var/mobile/Containers/

Comment: If you update the full code where you are getting error i can fix it :)

Comment: always you breakpoints so you get to know where you are wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98246/discussion-between-o-mkar-and-matt).

Comment: You were right all along, your updated code worked like a charm

Comment: I used rebekka to uploaded image on FTP server, but now I want to show progressBar to uploaded image in swift iOS.